# Can I run extension in incognito mode by default?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want my extension to work in both modes.
Is this possible by default, maybe some option in the manifest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No such option, user needs to manually allow an extension to run in incognito mode.

Comment: It is, but the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438354/how-can-i-enable-my-chrome-extension-in-incognito-mode is more helpful.