# Chrome ExtensionInstallForcelist policy and "Allow in incognito"

Tags: google-chrome-extension

When I install an extension in Google Chrome using Group Policy ExtensionInstallForcelist (http://dev.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#ExtensionInstallForcelist), the extension is indeed installed & prevents removal or disabling - however, the following options are no longer available/visible on the Chrome Extensions page for this extension:

> Allow in incognito
>
> Allow access to file URLs
>
> Options

If possible, I'd like to also force (or default) "Allow in incognito" to be enabled, but if that's not possible, I at least need to give the user the ability to enable this option.  Is there anything I can do about this? I believe I've read all the related documentation, and I haven't found anything...

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1):

This was already answered here: [Can I run extension in incognito mode by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200184/can-i-run-extension-in-incognito-mode-by-default).

I believe it was [already requested as a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=55058&q=incognito%20extension%20permission&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary), how about starring or commenting there?

Edit: Apparently there is also an open bug [over here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224857)

Comment: That may answer part of the question, though the root question still stands: why does ExtensionInstallForcelist remove the “Allow in incognito” option altogether, and is there anything I can do about it?  Yes, I would like to auto-default it to checked, but I'd also settle for the user being able to check the box - but the box is hidden altogether. This behavior is not documented anywhere (that I've seen), hence my question here.  I've seen nowhere that discusses "Allow in Incognito" in relation to these Group Policies.

Comment: Hmm, is IncognitoModeAvailability policy set to 1 by any chance? or IncognitoEnabled to disabled?

Comment: Nope, Incognito mode is enabled, and IncognitoModeAvailability is unset. When I use Incognito, my extension is not active - but it is active in Incognito when "Allow in Incognito" is checked on the Extensions page (when the extension is installed normally).

I'm also not sure if I should consider this a "bug", or a "feature"...  I've also verified that this behavior is identical on Windows and Mac for ExtensionInstallForcelist, with the latest stable Chrome.

Comment: This should probably files as a bug since at the very least it's an undocumented behavior...

Comment: FYI to anyone interested, there is an open Chromium issue regarding this: [link](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=224857)