# How can I enable my chrome extension in incognito mode?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, incognito-mode

I created an extension for Google Chrome and would like to know if it is possible for my extension to be enabled in incognito mode.

Ex: `chrome.extension ...... allowedIncognitoAccess = true`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's not possible to automatically activate incognito mode for Chrome extensions.

Instead of letting the user figure out where the option can be found, just instruct the user to put a check on the checkbox at the extension.

- To detect whether incognito is enabled, use the [`chrome.extension.isAllowedIncognitoAccess`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-isAllowedIncognitoAccess) method.
- After showing the instructons to the user, use [`chrome.tabs.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-create) or [`chrome.tabs.update`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-update) to open **`chrome://extensions/?id=YOUR EXTENSION ID HERE`**. The extension ID can be read programatically through the [`chrome.runtime.id`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#property-id) property. Chrome recognizes the `id` query parameter and highlights the specified extension in the list of extensions, as seen in the next picture (notice the gray background):

[image]

In terms of code:

```js
chrome.extension.isAllowedIncognitoAccess(function(isAllowedAccess) {
    if (isAllowedAccess) return; // Great, we've got access

    // alert for a quick demonstration, please create your own user-friendly UI
    alert('Please allow incognito mode in the following screen.');

    chrome.tabs.create({
        url: 'chrome://extensions/?id=' + chrome.runtime.id
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Users may manually enable specific extensions in incognito mode by visiting the extensions settings page.

- Chrome menu
- Settings
- Extensions (on left side navigation bar)
- Check "Allow in incognito" next to the individual extension to be enabled.

See [Manage your extensions](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/187443?hl=en) in Chrome help.

Comment: Thank you, but i need this to be done automatically by line of code.