# Adding file://. permission to chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chromium

How can I enable permissions for file:/// using chrome extensions.
In my manifest.json I have tried:

```
"permissions": [
  "file:///*"
]
```

and

```
"permissions": [
  "file://*"
]
```

as well as

```
"permissions": [
  "*:///C"
]
```

None of these work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
"permissions": [
    "file://*/*"
]
```

Unless the extension is loaded from your local disk, file access will be disabled by default. The user has to manually approve this permission by visiting `chrome://extensions/` and put a tick at the "Allow access to file URLs" checkbox.

In your code, you can see whether file access is allowed using [`chrome.extension.isAllowedFileSchemeAccess`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension.html#method-isAllowedFileSchemeAccess).

For a user-friendly way of requesting this access, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17443982/938089).