# How to access file and directory structure outside the sandbox from chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I know about file system api exposed to native client but it seems it can not allow access outside sandbox. There is an api which can allow access outside sandbox by a prompt window.

If my understanding is correct it can not allow access to a directory. I recently came across chrome dev which allow you to create workspace in any directory and allows cut, copy and paste operations even at directory level. I am wondering how are they getting the access to files and directory outside sandbox.

The extension which I am referring is:
https://github.com/dart-lang/chromedeveditor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Chrome Dev Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-dev-editor-develop/pnoffddplpippgcfjdhbmhkofpnaalpg) is not a Chrome extension, but a Chrome App. Chrome Apps can use the [`chrome.fileSystem`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) API to read and write to directories and files that are selected by a user.

Extensions can only access a sandboxed filesystem using the non-extension-specific [FileSystem API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-file-system-api-20120417/). The only API that allows extensions to write outside the virtual filesystem is [`chrome.downloads.download`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-download), which allows extensions to save a file to a directory as chosen by the user. After this operation, an extension can delete, but not modify the (downloaded) file.

(and if your extension requests the `file://*/*` or `<all_urls>` permission **and** the user ticks the "Allow access to file URLs" checkbox at the Extensions page, then your extension will have read-only access to the user's filesystem; if you want to pursue this method, read https://stackoverflow.com/a/19493206)