# Determine if Allow access to file URLs is enabled (chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I can direct my users to enable Allow access to file URLs by going to chrome:extensions and ticking the box.  I am wondering if there is any easy way to check if this is enabled?  I could check by having chrome read a file at that address with an ajax request and seeing if it is denied.  But is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check file access is allowed using [chrome.extension.isAllowedFileSchemeAccess](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-isAllowedFileSchemeAccess).

For more information you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493020/adding-file-permission-to-chrome-extension).