# Blocked cross-origin frame in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension, so by definition it runs inside the browser. I have been studying some other posts with similar issues:

[Chrome Extension - Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159999/chrome-extension-uncaught-domexception-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-acces)

[SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)

https://forums.asp.net/t/2119174.aspx?Blocked+a+frame+with+origin+from+accessing+a+cross+origin+frame+

In my extension code I'm doing the following:

```
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
```

In a previous version of Chrome, early in 2018 or maybe going back to 2017, this code worked fine, but now it throws this error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin
>   "https://play.google.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
>       at eval (eval at getGooglePlayVideoArray (chrome-extension://mabfegpcoejeoliboopmoeoodfiocgcn/js/ZingFilter.js:727:27),
>   :1:22)
>       at getGooglePlayVideoArray (chrome-extension://mabfegpcoejeoliboopmoeoodfiocgcn/js/ZingFilter.js:727:27)
>       at loadVideo (chrome-extension://mabfegpcoejeoliboopmoeoodfiocgcn/js/ZingFilter.js:760:21)
>       at chrome-extension://mabfegpcoejeoliboopmoeoodfiocgcn/js/ZingFilter.js:493:46

What I don't understand is how Chrome can see this as cross-origin given the fact that my extension js is injected right into the browser page. What makes it think it's cross-origin? Is my only solution to resort to [this](https://forums.asp.net/t/2119174.aspx?Blocked%20a%20frame%20with%20origin%20from%20accessing%20a%20cross%20origin%20frame%20)?

Comment: Have you added `"all_frames": true` to the content_scripts?

Comment: wOxxOm: https://play.google.com/store/movies/details?id=RGSNWMLe13g (you'll have to pay to watch it) - Peter: I had `all_frames` set to `false`. I changed it to true and reloaded my extension. No change, same error.

Comment: To bad, maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)/answer fixes it..

Comment: Peter, I'm sure that would fix it, but I don't control end users' browsers and cannot ask them to do that.

Comment: @HerrimanCoder, I see the same behavior in devtools console in the main page context so evidently this is a consequence of `allow` attribute which defines [Feature Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Feature_Policy). The way it's implemented now doesn't account for chrome extensions because iclelland@chromium.org who implemented it in Chrome didn't care/know about it. The usual workaround is to declare a content script to run in that iframe and then communicate via DOM messaging or chrome messaging. BTW use `@` prefix before a user name to notify that user.

Comment: @wOxxOm, thanks, but when I use `@` prefix before username, the username sometimes disappears entirely, which really puzzles me.

Comment: IIRC it disappears only when the mentioned user's comment is the last one - because your comment would trigger notification for that user in this case automatically.