# Chrome Extension Incognito mode service registration failed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension with MV3, I configured my manifest to work on private windows

`"incognito": "split"`

and It is working properly If I allow private mode [image: Allow congnito]

It works.

Whenever I open a private window without allowing the extension, I get this error:

> Service worker registration failed

[image]

Any solution to that to solve this error?

EDIT:
I use

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener
chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener
```

In my background script when I delete them, error doesn't occur

Comment: It's either a bug in Chrome or a mistake in your code. You can delete half of it and see if the problem is gone, then repeat the process progressively until you have the smallest part that causes the error.

Comment: Even if I put empty chrome.tabs or chrome.windows It produces this error. It probably can't react them since user didn't allow the private usage. I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/23527746/13587169 this but didn't work as well.

Comment: A registration error means something outside a listener, so changing the inside won't help, which is why I suggested removing in halves. You also need to reload the extension after editing it.

Comment: I mean, I deleted all my code in background scriptp then put a chrome tabs onUpdate method which logs a string, It instantly produces the error when I open incognito window . But when I delete all code and just put a console log error doesn't occur