# ChromeDriver Load Preconfigured Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

How can one load a preconfigured extension in [ChromeDriver](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)?

Adding the extension with `options.addExtensions(new File("path\\to\\fileName.crx));` installs it and obviously has its default options. Eventually it opens a new tab telling you that the extension has been installed.

Loading all extensions from the Chrome Extensions directory does nothing, no extensions are additionally made available:

```
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--load-extension=C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extensions"));
```

Also, how can extensions run in [`incognito mode`](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en) this way? Is it possible to enabale that using Selenium [or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438354/how-can-i-enable-my-chrome-extension-in-incognito-mode)?