# Loading Chrome Profile Not Working (ChromeDriver)

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to load my Chrome profile for use with [`Selenium WebDriver`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) but it doesn't work and always defaults to a new one. I tried the codes provided from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480717/load-chrome-profile-using-selenium-webdriver).

Is there any workaround or fix? I'd like to run `ChromeDriver` with customized extensions, options and whatnot since [`command line flags`](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) and `ChromeOptions` have restricted functionality.

Also, I'm having another issue about [loading preconfigured extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442340/chromedriver-load-preconfigured-extension).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.But I did something like this and it worked.

```
String userProfile= "C:/Users/"your user"/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User";
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=" + userProfile);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Please let me know if it work also for you.

Comment: how could I load multiple instances of these profile at the same time ? Chromedriver is not thread safe

Comment: is this a question ? or you wanted to mention that ?