# How to trigger a click on a chrome extension button?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, ui-automation

I'm building an **automated test suite** using Selenium Web Driver. At a certain point I must test how the page works by having a **Chrome extension turn on or off**. Think of it as you would want to click on the Adblock extension and then click disable for this site. Then, turn it on again. 
I searched all over the Internet and **there is no way to implement this using just Selenium**. **Do you know how could I perform such an action? (from Java ideally)**

Comment: On blazemeter is a nice description available, that probably also works for you: [Blazemeter-way of testing crx extesion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-easy-steps-testing-your-chrome-extension-selenium)

Comment: Did you try to use [ChromeOptions](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/extensions)? it allows you to set desired extensions for a run, so one test could use those and the next one - not.

Comment: This is a really good tip! I could use it as a last resort. Ideally, I would like to turn the extension on/off by pressing the button and check how the site reacts. Thanks! ;)

Comment: Turned the comment into answer so ppl can find it easily and vote if it is helpful.

Comment: As we know, we cannot click on any browser extension using selenium webdriver, the best alternative is to use sikuli.
Download the Jar file from "https://launchpad.net/sikuli/+download"
Add to your library and follow the steps mentioned by piet.t. It worked for me..

Answer (score 3):

Below is the solution is in Python with pyautogui (I believe it's similar to **autoit** in java - so you can extend the same solution for **java also**).

**Pre-Condition:**

save the extension image in the project folder (I saved it under "autogui_ref_snaps" folder in my example with "capture_full_screenshot.png" name

**Python:**

*Imports needed*

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
import pyautogui  #<== need this to click on extension
```

*Script:*

```
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--load-extension=" + r"C:\Users\supputuri\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl\5.1_0") #<== loading unpacked extension

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
executable_path=os.path.join(chrome_options=options)
url = "https://google.com/"
driver.get(url)

# get the extension box
extn = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.join(GenericMethods.get_full_path_to_folder('autogui_ref_snaps') + "/capture_full_screenshot.png"))
# click on extension 
pyautogui.click(x=extn[0],y=extn[1],clicks=1,interval=0.0,button="left")
```

If you are loading an extension and it's not available in incognito mode then follow my answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534688/enabling-chrome-extension-in-incognito-mode-via-cli-flags/56410914#56410914) to enable it.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to go with [Chrome options](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/extensions) and manage the extensions set to the WebDriver. Quick example:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addExtensions(new File("/path/to/extension.crx"));
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

If you want to turn those On and OFF in a single test, you can spawn two separate drivers and compare the results, since I'm not sure that session reuse will do the job in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Can use sikuli(GUI Automation tool) to click on browser addon.

Imports needed:

```
    import org.sikuli.script.Pattern;
    import org.sikuli.script.Screen;
```

Script:

```
    Pattern addon=new Pattern("D:\\My Files\\Addon.jpg");  //image of the addon must be given as a pattern for identifying that on the browser/webpage
    Screen s=new Screen();
    s.hover(addon);
    s.click(addon);
```