# Is there a way to click on the chrome extension i just installed using java/selenium?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am automating my test case where I need to install an extension and click on it and perform some action after that.
I am able to install the plugin but not able to click on the same since selenium/ LeanFT isn't allowing me to do so.
Please suggest how do I do that?

What I have tried -
Actions class in java to click on x,y coordinates - not helping me!

Thanks
Manav

Comment: Have a look at this question : [How to trigger a click on a chrome extension button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47042409/how-to-trigger-a-click-on-a-chrome-extension-button)

Comment: @MikeManders If you see point 4 in the solution there, it says "identify the page that you want to test", and I don't wanna test a page, it's just a click on the icon, unable to figure out using that answer, any help you think you can do?
Just wanted to add - GeoEdge is the plugin that I want to click on and change my location, thats the mission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to click on the icon(plugin/extension icon) using image matching technique of Sikuli.
Thanks for the contribution though. Appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seems to be an easy way to directly click the icon in your chrome browser. 
However extensions normally have some pages you can access like an options or login page ,and you can work from there.

To figure out the url:

1. Navigate in your browser to 'chrome://extensions/'
2. Find the extensions your are working with (GeoEdge in your case)
3. Make sure the developer mode is activated in the top right, otherwise activate it in the chrome settings
4. You should be able to see the ID of the extension now
5. Navigate to desired page: 'chrome://extensions/EXTENSIONID/PAGE.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: not really helping, i was able to click on it using Sikuli though, but then selecting the location seems tough as the drop down moves away with mouse hover off it, cant inspect elements there !