# Is there any method to click on extension icon in chrome tool bar using java selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Basically i have installed a vpn extension .All i want to do is to open the extension and select a specific country location.

Comment: Is there anything that you've tried sir ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger a click on a chrome extension button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47042409/how-to-trigger-a-click-on-a-chrome-extension-button)