# python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Common_Methods'

Tags: python, selenium, pip

I am trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61628228/scheduled-trigger-of-chrome-extension-app) example of generating a click on the extension.
below is my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pyautogui
import json
import os
from Common_Methods.GenericMethods import *

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--load-extension=./Edit-This-Cookie")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=options)

driver.get("https://google.com")
# get the extension box
extn = pyautogui.locateOnScreen(os.path.join(GenericMethods.get_full_path_to_folder() + "/icon_16x16.png"))
# click on extension 
pyautogui.click(x=extn[0],y=extn[1],clicks=1,interval=0.0,button="left")
```

I am getting the error

```
    from Common_Methods.GenericMethods import *
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Common_Methods'
```

I tried to check if there is any module by that name in pip, but there are none.
I am presently using python version `3.9.0`, I tried switching to `2.7` but the package still seems missing.

EDIT:
removing the `from Common_Methods.GenericMethods import *`
gives the following error:-

```
NameError: name 'GenericMethods' is not defined
```

Comment: not sure what you need that module for, if you cant find how to install it, you possibly have to take a another module that you can install, since for everything there are mostly multiple solutions

Comment: @Timeler not sure if you can.see that GenericMethods is needed in the path

Comment: i can see it, but again if that module doesnt seem to exist, which seems to be the non-existant, you have to find another solution as @PDHide said

Answer (score 0):

```
from Common_Methods.GenericMethods import *
```

That seems to be a package specific to thier framework you can simply remove it

```
extn = pyautogui.locateOnScreen("absolutepathtofile/icon_16x16.png")
```

Comment: removing that package impot throws error for genericmethod. Please check the edit

Comment: @souparnomajumder don't simply copy paste code find alternative of what the  are trying to do , like usiong python path or something

Comment: @souparnomajumder just provided full path instead of calling the generic method . Give full path to the image file