# Need help to click on the element under the shadow Root (closed) type

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, shadow-dom, sfdc

Null Pointer Exception on click at the element located inside of the shadow Root (closed)

Tried to handle it with Java Script:

```
public WebElement getShadowRootElement(WebElement element) {
    return (WebElement)
            ((JavascriptExecutor)
                    driver).executeScript("return 
arguments[0].shadowRoot", element);
}
```

[image]

Result:

```
Cannot read property 'shadowRoot' of null
```

Added screenshots:
1. [image]

[image]

Comment: What's your element? Is it `use` tag?

Comment: @supputuri the element is a button that is above of the root. But when I'm clicking on this button it returns NPE again. That's why I decided to dig dipper to the svg / path

Comment: `shadow-root` is not attached to button. So you have to use xpath `//button//use[@lightning-primitiveIcon_primitiveIcon]` as the `shadowHost` as mentioned in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534688/enabling-chrome-extension-in-incognito-mode-via-cli-flags)

Comment: Also check if `button` is under shadow-root.

Comment: as you can see the button is under the shadow-root. Logically the browser should click on it, but it failed with NPE too. So weird.

Comment: Check my comment and updated answer (that helps you to find the shadow element path).

Comment: I've realized what's wrong with the element identifier. Before clicking that button the driver switched to the iframe that frame prevents driver to locate the "close" button web element. Now need to figure how to get out of that frame.

Comment: Simply, switch to default window.

Comment: @Y_Sh does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77242284/how-to-locate-element-in-shadow-root-closed-host

Answer (score 4):

If your usecase is to interact with the `<path>` element which is within the `<svg>` tag, is indeed within a **`#shadow-root (closed)`**.

@hayatoito (creator of Shadow DOM) in this [comment](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/378#issuecomment-179596975) clearly mentions:

> The original motivation of introducing a closed shadow tree is **`"Never allow an access to a node in a closed shadow tree, via any APIs, from outside"`**, AFAIK. Like that we can not access a node in the internal hidden shadow tree which is used in `<video>` element, in Blink.
>
> In fact, I designed a closed shadow tree in such a way. If there is a way to access a node in a closed shadow tree, it should be considered as a bug of the spec.
>
> I think it's totally okay to have an API to allow an access in the layer of Chrome apps or extensions.
>   However, for a normal web app, I think the current agreement is **`"Never allow it"`**.
>
> If we allowed it, that means we do not need a closed shadow tree. Just having an open shadow tree is enough, I think.

---

### WebDriver perspective

Recently, @AutomatedTester [David Burns, Chief Bacon Officer, Mozilla Corporation] initiated a discussion on [WebDriver - Testability of web components](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/771)

- [Requests](https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr+is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+shadow+dom+)
- [Proposals](https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr+is%3Aopen+shadow)
- [Issue Tracker](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/354)

Currently *Selenium Team* is open for accepting pull requests for the same.

---

### Outro

Here you can find a relevant discussion on [How to automate shadow DOM elements using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution.

```
WebElement closeElement = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('button[title='Close Order Status'] svg use').shadowRoot.querySelector('svg path')");
closeElement.click();
```

**Quick Way to find path**

Just providing the screenshot which will give the idea how to find the path. (FYI this screenshot is for the clear data button in the chrome clear history)
[image]

Comment: Are you able to click on the path element now?

Comment: Thanks, tried that but the xpath: //button[@title='Close Order Status']//use  with "//use" identifier could NOT be located through the console neither through selenium: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@title='Close Order Status']//use"}

Comment: Can you please share the screenshot of the `Dev Tools > Element tab` base where you see the css path. As shown under `Quick Way to find path` in my updated answer.

Comment: Added few screenshots. Please see the main description.

Comment: Check the updated answer. `button[title='Close Order Status'] svg use` is the correct shadow-host element, this should work now.

Comment: nope, it didn't find any element and no output from the DevTools-> Elements. I've change the xpath to //button[@title='Close Order Status']/lightning-primitive-icon//*[@data-key]//* and it finally is searchable on DevTools, but the web driver is still unable to locate this element.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression button[title='Close Order Status'] svg use because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'button[title='Close Order Status'] svg use' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: `button[title='Close Order Status'] svg use` is css, not xpath.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Still NPE. The problem with the 'Close Order Status' button is that its element could no be located at all. Tried to get size, location but it always return: element not found.

Comment: ok, can you try the this xpath `//button[@title='Close Order Status']//*[local-name()='use']`. Check if this return the `use` element, this should be a separate step but in the javascript that I provided.

Comment: Let me know if that return the `use` element, then I can update the answer to use the `use` element in javascript.

Comment: the above js with return document.querySelector ?

Comment: `document.querySelector('button[title='Close Order Status'] svg use')` run this in your chrome console and see if you get the `use` element.

Comment: NPE when clicking on the return web element:

Comment: Sorry, can you check it in the browser console. Not in your script

Comment: I can find the path in the console(dev tools), but the driver is NOT able to find that element and always returns NPE: element is not found. That's the problem. I've tried all options: xpath, css. Same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript something like this.

```
WebElement clearData = (WebElement) js.executeScript("return document.querySelector('button[title='Close Order Status'] svg use').shadowRoot.querySelector('svg path')");
```

Check [How to locate the #shadow-root (open) elements through cssSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-locate-the-shadow-root-open-elements-through-cssselector/56381495#56381495) link for more information.

Comment: check the updated answer, updated javascript with the tag based on your screenshot.

Comment: this only works for (open) shadowRoot, but i have (closed)

Comment: @userFollow Updated your answer by mistake.  However, this would be the correct answer.