# How to read text that is under #shadow-root (user-agent)

Tags: python, selenium, dom, polymer, shadow-dom

I am using Selenium (Python) for automating a web page. I am trying to get text from an input field that is under #shadow-root (user-agent).
Xpath I used:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("**//*/p-calendar/span/input**").text
```

is not returning anything.
Attached the screenshot of my DOM element.
Requirement: To get text from the shadow root : 01:01

[image: #shadow-root (user-agent)]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per `@hayatoito`'s (creator of Shadow DOM) [comment](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/378#issuecomment-179596975):

> The original motivation of introducing a closed shadow tree is **`"Never allow an access to a node in a closed shadow tree, via any APIs, from outside"`**, AFAIK. Like that we can not access a node in the internal hidden shadow tree which is used in `<video>` element, in Blink.

> In fact, I designed a closed shadow tree in such a way. If there is a way to access a node in a closed shadow tree, it should be considered as a bug of the spec.

> I think it's totally okay to have an API to allow an access in the layer of Chrome apps or extensions.
> However, for a normal web app, I think the current agreement is **`"Never allow it"`**.

> If we allowed it, that means we do not need a closed shadow tree. Just having an open shadow tree is enough, I think.

Furhter `@Supersharp` in his comment below his own answer within the discussion [How to get element in user-agent shadow root with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38701803/how-to-get-element-in-user-agent-shadow-root-with-javascript/38736220#38736220) mentions:

> ***`#shadow-root (user-agent)` are browser vendors native implementation so they are not documented and will never be accessible. Only open Shadow DOM are, as per the specs***

---

### WebDriver perspective

Recently, @AutomatedTester [David Burns, Chief Bacon Officer, Mozilla Corporation] initiated a discussion on [WebDriver - Testability of web components](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/771)

- [Requests](https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr+is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+shadow+dom+)
- [Proposals](https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/pulls?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Apr+is%3Aopen+shadow)
- [Issue Tracker](https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/354)

Currently *Selenium Team* is open for accepting pull requests for the same.

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Need help to click on the element under the shadow Root (closed) type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56500290/need-help-to-click-on-the-element-under-the-shadow-root-closed-type/56501498#56501498)

---

### Outro

Here you can find a relevant discussion on [How to automate shadow DOM elements using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `driver.execute_script` to inject JavaScript code that returns the ShadowRoot then use `find_element` to get the children element of the shadow root you are looking for.

```
input_shadow = driver.execute_script('''return document.querySelector("$1").shadowRoot''')
div_text = inputShadow.find_element_by_tag_name("div").text
```

$1 - `Your element's identifier or selector`.

If you are keen to using xpath to find elements

```
input_shadow = driver.execute_script('''return $x(\"//*/p-calendar/span/input\")[0]''')
div_text = inputShadow.find_element_by_tag_name("div").text
```

Answer (score 0):

If your control is inside Shadow-root (user-agent). You can perform enter text, get value and click by using the Parent of Shadow-root (user-agent).

Example: Considering HTML DOM shared in question.

(Selenium/C# code) - same should work for others as well

```
//You can use any identifier like id, XPath, tagname, etc
Var element = Driver.FindElement(By.Tagname("input"));
//Text will return null, so use below code
var text = element.GetAttribute("value");
or
element.Click();
or
element.Sendkeys("Etered text");
```