# How to edit #shadow-root (user-agent) value in selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium, dom, polymer, shadow-dom

My working environment is Python, Chrome, Selenium

I want to edit shadow-root (user-agent)'s value

```
    <div class="divclass">
      <input type="tel" id="mytel" name="telamount" data-wheel-step="100" class="oneclass" value="1">
        #shadow-root (user-agent)
          <div>1</div>
      </input>
</div>
```

If I'm using js's `.getAttribute()`, with input's id "mytel" that can attach the value 1, but it isn't attach shadow-root.

I want change `<div>`'s 1

I've been looking hard, but I don't even know if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The value is within a *`#shadow-root (user-agent)`*

@dylanb in one of his [comment](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/354#issue-120429803) clearly mentions the following:

> If web components are created with the closed flag and these web
> components create interactive elements within their shadow DOM, it is
> not possible for auditing tools to check for the validity of that
> markup.

Further he also adds:

> In addition, if a user of that component wishes to use automation
> tools like Selenium to automate the testing of that component, it is
> not possible to interact with the shadow DOM components.

The two possible solutions he spoke about are:

- Remove this closed flag altogether
- Expose the composed tree through a set of APIs that will allow automation and auditing to occur regardless of the closed/open mode. This should include an API to efficiently discover and return the DOM nodes that have a shadow root and should allow for querySelector* to operate within this composed tree.

But these steps are beyond the scope of Selenium.

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [How to read text that is under #shadow-root (user-agent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63925112/how-to-read-text-that-is-under-shadow-root-user-agent/63927668#63927668)