# Cannot input date to field with shadow-root (user-agent) with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to write a stable code to input a date into calendar input field.
Native Selenium inputs work only locally, but when I run this code in CICD I see that numbers are sometime inputted into wrong places.

For example, the timestamp is `2022-07-22 00:56:42.`
Expected input by user is `220720220056`.
By experimenting I found out that year works if there are two zeros in front of the year. Therefore, what I actually send is `22070020220056`

```
    input_field = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@role='dialog']//input[@type='datetime-local']")
    input_field.click()
    input_field.clear()
    input_field.send_keys(22070020220056)
```

```html
<input _ngcontent-pau-c188="" clrinput="" type="datetime-local" name="expiry" aria-describedby="clr-form-control-9-helper" id="clr-form-control-9" class="clr-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
#shadow-root (user-agent) == $0
<div pseudo="-webkit-datetime-edit" id="date-time-edit" datetimeformat="dd/MM/y, HH:mm">
    <div pseudo="-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper">
        <span role="spinbutton" aria-placeholder="dd" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="31" aria-label="Day" pseudo="-webkit-datetime-edit-day-field" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuetext="25">25</span>
        <div pseudo="-webkit-datetime-edit-text">/</div>
        <span role="spinbutton" aria-placeholder="mm" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="12" aria-label="Month" pseudo="-webkit-datetime-edit-month-field" aria-valuenow="7" aria-valuetext="07">07</span>
        <div pseudo="-webkit-datetime-edit-text">/</div>
        <span role="spinbutton" aria-placeholder="yyyy" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="275760" aria-label="Year" pseudo="-webkit-datetime-edit-year-field" aria-valuenow="2022" aria-valuetext="2022">2022</span>
        <div pseudo="-webkit-datetime-edit-text">, </div>
        <span role="spinbutton" aria-placeholder="--" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="23" aria-label="Hours" pseudo="-webkit-datetime-edit-hour-field" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuetext="00">00</span>
        <div pseudo="-webkit-datetime-edit-text">:</div>
        <span role="spinbutton" aria-placeholder="--" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="59" aria-label="Minutes" pseudo="-webkit-datetime-edit-minute-field" aria-valuenow="1" aria-valuetext="01">01</span>
    </div>
</div>
</input>
```

[image]

Field looks like this:
[image]

I tried few other options to make the test more stable.

**Option 1.**

Tried to set the value directly.

```
driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '{my_timestamp}')", input_field)
```

**Option 2**

Tried to access shadow root:

```
date_field = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('input[type=datetime-local]').shadowRoot.getElementById('#date-time-edit')")
date_field.send_keys(my_timestamp)
```

**Option 3**

Tried to get parent element with `execute_script` instead of Selenium and send value:

```
date_field = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('input[type=datetime-local]')")
date_field.send_keys(my_timestamp)
```

**Option 4**

Tried to send text with a small delay before each letter:

```
    for letter in timestamp:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print(f"Sending letter {letter}")
        date_field.send_keys(letter)
```

None of these methods worked on CICD, Only initial one and Option 3 always work locally.

I think the only stable solution would be the use of Javascipt code, but still not sure.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any urls or anything to test on >?

Comment: I would like to, but it's unfortunately a closed application. I'll try any advice. I'll think what other details I can share.

Comment: So looking through the options that work 1,3 work since it doesn't seem to be in the shadow root. How does it work with sending a format like "dd/MM/y" or maybe "dd/MM/y, HH:mm" to that input tag.

Comment: `my_timestamp = actual_time.strftime("%d%m00%Y%H%M")`

Comment: I'll try options suggested by you tomorrow

Comment: I think that I'm very close to solution because of your questions. I need to send this timestamp in Selenium with exact format. This is what I got in debugger: `The specified value "22070020221333" does not conform to the required format.  The format is "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm" followed by optional ":ss" or ":ss.SSS".`

Answer (score 1):

Ah yes, the shadow root. For me, what works is something like the following:

```
shadowRootElement = driver.execute_script('''return document.querySelector("selector for shadowRoot's parent").shadowRoot''')

shadowRootChild = driver.execute_script('''return arguments[0].querySelector("selector for shadowRoot's parent").shadowRoot''', shadowRootElement)

shadowRootChild.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type=datetime-local]').send_keys("This is a test");
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried both answers. Did not work yet, but gave me some new ideas

Answer (score 1):

The `<input>` looks perfectly out of [**#shadow-root (user-agent)**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63927668/7429447) ambit.

```
<input _ngcontent-pau-c188="" clrinput="" type="datetime-local" name="expiry" aria-describedby="clr-form-control-9-helper" id="clr-form-control-9" class="clr-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
#shadow-root (user-agent) == $0
    <div pseudo="-webkit-datetime-edit" id="date-time-edit" datetimeformat="dd/MM/y, HH:mm">
        <div pseudo="-webkit-datetime-edit-fields-wrapper">
        .
        .
        .
        </div>
    </div>
</input>
```

However, the desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, so ideally to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  input_field = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='clr-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched' and @name='expiry'][@type='datetime-local']")))
  driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '{my_timestamp}')", input_field)
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks. It did not work yet. But I'll try by myself with different locators and inputs