# How can i get #shadow-root (user-agent) Cypress JS

Tags: javascript, cypress, shadow-dom

If is any way how I can get to the #shadow-root (user-agent) element ???

Hi I need to change the value in div, I tried to change the input and it doesn't help me

[image]

Comment: Have you searched StackOverflow before asking the question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read text that is under #shadow-root (user-agent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63925112/how-to-read-text-that-is-under-shadow-root-user-agent)

Answer (score 4):

No, the `(user-agent)` tag tells you that the browser is implementing the shadow elements. In this case, they are read-only.

Nor should you attempt to modify it directly in a test, since it is internal implementation. You should interact with the `<input>` element itself, although it has a `readonly` attribute so you would have to `force` it.

```js
cy.get('input[id="PersonalDetails/tel"]')
  .type('123', {force:true})
  .trigger('change')
  .shadow()
  .find('div')
  .should('have.text', '123')
```