# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'ShadowRoot') - Java and Selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape using Java and Selenium but for one part of what I need to web scrape, it requires me to access a shadow DOM element. I am using Javascript executor to access it and I am entering the querySelector snippet needed to retrieve what I am looking for but I am getting a "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'ShadowRoot')" error. Is anyone familiar with this and how to solve it?

Here is my code snippet:

```
 String pagePdfUrl = (String) js.executeScript("document.querySelector('pdf-viewer').shadowRoot.getElementById('content').querySelector('embed').getAttribute('original-url')");
```

js is the JavascriptExectuor variable.

Thank you!

Comment: No way for use to tell what you are doing right or wrong. You've described it as if you've done everything correctly. The property is named `shadowRoot` rather than `ShadowRoot` if that makes a difference.

Comment: My apologies. I have just added a code snippet. Please let me know if you need any more information

Comment: Try putting `return ` between `"` and `document`.

Comment: [Reference](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...))

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either

Comment: the only thing left is your selector. It is returning `null`

Comment: I am testing this by going to the console of the webpage I'm accessing and entering this selector. It does not return null

Comment: I believe you. At the time you call `executeScript()`, the DOM element(s) your are attempting to find are not there - your call returns null. When you do it in the browser console the entire DOM has been constructed. I don't know if these are dynamic elements that are injected or what. But that, I believe is the issue.

Comment: They actually are dynamic elements I believe. Is there a way to work around that?

Comment: You can use `WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(...)` with an xPath selector. I would stick with xPath as there doesn't seem to be any reason not to. It will reduce the complexity of your test code.

Comment: You can't access shadow DOM elements using xPath, can you? Furthermore, can WebDriverWait.until() work with querySelectors?

Comment: Nope..., you could use `sleep()` I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

While using [*querySelector()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70194988/document-queryselector-is-not-showing-all-elements/70198069#70198069) to read a [*ShadowRoot*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-locate-the-shadow-root-open-elements-through-cssselector) this error message...

```
Cannot read properties of null
```

...implies either of the following circumstances:

- It's a [*#shadow-root (closed)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56500290/need-help-to-click-on-the-element-under-the-shadow-root-closed-type/56501498#56501498)
- It's a [*#shadow-root (user-agent)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63925112/how-to-read-text-that-is-under-shadow-root-user-agent/63927668#63927668)
- The contents within the [*#shadow-root (open)*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761810/how-to-automate-shadow-dom-elements-using-selenium/55763793#55763793) is not readily available.

---

### Solution

In case of the first and second scenario, you won't be able to access the [*ShadowRoot*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59168840/selenium-c-sharp-not-able-to-click-on-an-element-within-shadow-root-closed/59170870#59170870). Where as in the third case you need to wait for sometime e.g. `time.sleep(3)` before you attempt to access the [*ShadowRoot*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65044870/how-to-extract-info-within-a-shadow-root-open-using-selenium-python/65055114#65055114) and it's elements.

Comment: It is #shadow-root (open) but unfortunately a sleep delay still did not work

Comment: Then the script which you are executing needs to be validated first.

Comment: So when I enter my script into the console it does return what I am looking for, not sure if I can upload a picture through comments

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium 4.0, for Chromium versions 96+ you can use the `getShadowRoot()` method and avoid the JavaScript entirely.

A working example:

```
driver.get("http://watir.com/examples/shadow_dom.html");
WebElement shadowHost = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#shadow_host"));
SearchContext shadowRoot = shadowHost.getShadowRoot();
WebElement shadowContent = shadowRoot.findElement(By.cssSelector("#shadow_content"));
```

Source: https://titusfortner.com/2021/11/22/shadow-dom-selenium.html

Answer (score 0):

Thread.sleep(10); is working fine for me.

Still i see same kind of error for another shadow element

sometimes shadow DOM querySelector('q2-input'); might have changed its location.

so if error still persists check the perfect JSPath and validate in console