# How to click button inside #shadow-root (closed) using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, shadow-dom

I'm trying to click button inside `#shadow-root (closed)`, inside iframe

```
<iframe title="recaptcha challenge expires in two minutes" 
   <div class="button-holder help-button-holder">
      #shadow-root (closed)
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="chrome-extension://mpbjkejclgfgadiemmefgebjfooflfhl/src/solve/solver-button.css">
         <button tabindex="0" title="Solve the challenge" id="solver-button"></button>
   </div>
</iframe>
```

This is what I use to switch to iframe

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='recaptcha challenge expires in two minutes']")))
```

How can I click `//button[@id="solver-button"]`

Here are photos how it really looks

iframe-[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RP0ow.jpg)

button-[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zpyu3.jpg)

Comment: I faced the situation the same! Finally, I had to direct to the parent `div` to click. Then it works for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77242284/how-to-locate-element-in-shadow-root-closed-host

Answer (score 1):

Your line of code to switch to the [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) was perfect. However, the desired element is within a [***#shadow-root (closed)***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56501498/7429447) and using *Selenium* you won't be able to interact with the elements within [#shadow-root (closed)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59170870/7429447) because as per the discussion in [Shadow DOM traversal support](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5869):

- @43081j mentioned, for closed shadow roots it should just be accepted that you can't access it (throw an exception). So, we don't need to care about closed roots as we shouldn't be able to access them anyway.
- @AutomatedTester in his [spec proposal](https://github.com/w3c/webdriver/pull/1320) suggested the ability to move between a Shadow DOM context and the document context.