# Why doesn't chrome extension work on selenium after add more options?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-extension

I'm scraping some sites with selenium and proxies which need authentication so I use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55582136/how-to-set-proxy-with-authentication-in-selenium-chromedriver-python) extension to set proxy's credentials, at this point everything goes well.

```
def get_chromedriver(use_proxy=False, user_agent=None):
    path = os.path.abspath(
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), './drivers/current/', 'chromedriver.exe'))
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if use_proxy:
        pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

        with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
            zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
            zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)
        chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
    if user_agent:
        chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)
    return driver
```

However, I need to set the following options too

```
  chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
```

The whole function looks like this, nevertheless when I execute the code below the proxy is not set, instead uses my public address. What's wrong with my code?

```
def get_chromedriver(use_proxy=False, user_agent=None):
    path = os.path.abspath(
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), './drivers/current/', 'chromedriver.exe'))
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if use_proxy:
        pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

        with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
            zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
            zp.writestr("background.js", background_js)
        chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
    if user_agent:
        chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path,
                              chrome_options=chrome_options)
    return driver
```

Comment: `chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()` should be `chrome_options = Options()` when imported from `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options` Check out the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.options)

Comment: @It_is_Chris I just tied it without success

Comment: How are you calling the function? The params are set to `False` and `None`

Comment: Yeah, that's right. I just found that the incognito argument was disabling the extensions!

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
After some debugging and trying one by one argument I discovered that the `chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")` argument was blocking all the extensions in the browser. After being disabled it the program worked again. If someone else wants to add more extensions with the incognito argument should try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534688/enabling-chrome-extension-in-incognito-mode-via-cli-flags)