# Is it possible for an enterprise-installed extension to force "Allow in incognito" on?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, enterprise, group-policy, incognito-mode

I have developed an extension which is to be installed by enterprise policy.  I want this extension to always be active, even in Incognito mode.  I see that the policy setting IncognitoModeAvailability allows me to either:
 1. Never allow Incognito mode
 2. Always force Incognito mode
 3. Allow user to choose Incognito mode, which also allows user to choose if extension is to be functional in Incognito mode

Is there a way under Option 3 above to force the "Allow in incognito" checkbox to be checked, along with graying out the checkbox so that the user cannot prevent my extension from working in Incognito mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can't automatically activate incognito mode for Chrome extensions. Users need to manually allow an extension to run in incognito mode. To see: [How can I enable my chrome extension in incognito mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438354/how-can-i-enable-my-chrome-extension-in-incognito-mode?rq=1) and [Can I run extension in incognito mode by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200184/can-i-run-extension-in-incognito-mode-by-default)

Comment: Found this extension on the webstore which seems to do it --  the box is not checked, but it is grayed out.   Silverlight for Chrome 1.8.2
ID: cgnklfhofbcfndknbonklnijndoeknal

Comment: Allow in incognito is greyed out for apps, and apps do not show in incognito mode. To see the related issue here: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=120468

Comment: That particular item seems to be both an app and an extension.  Is that possible?  When I install other apps, they do not appear in the extension list.

Comment: A packaged app's manifest can have any field that's available to extensions, except for "browser_action" and "page_action" and also can be seen in the extension list.